# cannot run application in jetty after including swagger in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, guava, embedded-jetty, swagger

I was able to run my Spring MVC appication, until the point where I introduced swagger dependency for the API documentation.

Now when I run the application in jetty server[Run as -> Run Jetty], I get the below error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;
    at com.mangofactory.swagger.scanners.ApiListingReferenceScanner.getResourceGroupRequestMappings(ApiListingReferenceScanner.java:146)
```

Searching the web, I see comments on upgrading the `com.google.guava` to 15.0 version, but still the issue persists.

Changes made that triggered the error: pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

and the SwaggerConfig.java  for Enabling swagger as mentioned here : http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-configure-swagger-generate

I'm stuck, please help

Update: Running in tomcat, but not in jetty

**Update [11/11]:**

1. upgraded swagger version to 0.9.1
2. upgraded guava version to 18.0
3. `mvn dependency:tree` shows only one guava version

   com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile

Even now the same issue exists!

Answer (score 2):

You might have multiple Guava dependencies on your classpath, in which case the `Multimaps` class from Guava 15.0 might be "hidden" by the `Multimaps` class from an earlier Guava version (or even Google Collections version).

You should run `mvn dependency:tree` to see if Guava 15.0 is the only Guava dependency, or if other versions are included (usually by transitive dependencies from some other library).

If you find such dependencies, you should [exclude them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028534/how-to-exclude-dependency-in-a-maven-plugin) in your pom.xml.

*Remark: if those libraries where depending on classes and/or methods that were removed in Guava 15.0, you might need to upgrade them instead. But it shouldn't happen if they stay away from @Beta APIs, as they should.*

---

Edit:

Since it doesn't seem to be a dependency conflict according to your output of `mvn dependency:tree`, maybe it's related to this [issue](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/issues/441), where Glassfish was bundling a different version of Guava? You are not using Glassfish, but it might be worth looking at the dependencies your App Server might be adding to the classpath.

More info:
- https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1668
- https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20850

Comment: Thank you, I will analyze and come back with the dependency tree. I remember I checked for this in Dependency hierarchy in pom.xml on Eclipse IDE. But lemme check again

Comment: The mvn dependency:tree showed up only one guava version. Please see my update in the post

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately I cant do another +1 :).. I will accept as answer once I find the same for jetty. Thank you Etienne

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to add to such an old post, but two years later I got stuck on the same problem.
It seems that the swagger-webmvc references dependencies that are not listed in the maven dependency tree. This might be because this project (and its successor springfox-swagger2) internally use Gradle instead of Maven.

The solution that helped me was adding the following exclusion for guava to (my two) springfox dependencies:

```
<exclusions>
      <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
               <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```