# Maven configure plugin dependencies

Tags: java, maven

First of all there are so many posts around this subject but i failed to resolve this issue.

I have my own maven repository and the process of bringing new jar into it is difficult, because of organisation security compliance.

what i am looking for is exclude jars from plugin and add available dependency inside plugin. please suggest required configuration?

Currently project build is failing because few essential jars are missing.

**pom**-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency></dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
 <!-- ${argLine} -->    
       <suiteXmlFiles>                           <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                     </suiteXmlFiles>
                     <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
                   <!-- <skip>true</skip>-->

                </configuration>
 </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

**Build error:**

```
[WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-testng:jar:2.18.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.055s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 15 11:50:31 MST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/363M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project cxp: Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-testng:jar:2.18.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=surefire-testng -Dversion=2.18.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
[ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=surefire-testng -Dversion=2.18.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR] 1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
[ERROR] 2) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-testng:jar:2.18.1
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] ----------
[ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] for artifact:
[ERROR] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] prod ****************************************************, releases=true, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have `org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-testng:jar:2.12.4` in repository so I modified plugin with below changes but maven still throws same error.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine> <!-- ${argLine} -->
                     <suiteXmlFiles>
                         <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                     </suiteXmlFiles>
                     <debugForkedProcess>true</debugForkedProcess>
                   <!-- <skip>true</skip>-->

                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: If the dependency is transitive, there might be a hope as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7405917/1667004), but as of [MNG-2163 JIRA ticket in Maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2163)  exclusions are not yet implemented for plugins...

Comment: Explained in answer is the different scenario. thanks for response.

Comment: Noticed that your POM's `<dependencies>` tag is not closed correctly (missing the backslash in the closing element)....

Comment: my pom file is very huge, i copied part of it. I missed it while copying.

Comment: did you try installing it manually 'surefire-testng' jar?

Comment: yes it works when i install locally.