# How to exclude a direct dependency of a Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I want to exclude a direct dependency of a Maven plugin and the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028534/2525313) does not work (as indicated by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028534/how-to-exclude-dependency-in-a-maven-plugin#comment72835581_7405917)).

As a particular example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.2</version>
            <!-- more config -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.2</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I still see `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` in the list of dependencies (with `mvn ... -X`). What am I doing wrong?

(In case someone has an idea for how to replace the dependency on that artifact with the JDK 9 equivalent for that API [as seems to happen on Java 8, where "JAXB API os loaded from the [jar:...jre/lib/rt.jar]"], I'm happy to open a new issue for that.)

### Update

Running out of ideas and this being an experiment anyways, I excluded the dependency by editing the plugin's `pom.xml` in my local repository. Now `mvn ... -X` shows that there is also an indirect dependency (in this case by `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin`) that I can successfully exclude with the mechanism above. Just using both excludes, from `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and `maven-jaxb22-plugin`, does not do the trick. This indicates that exclusion works in general but apparently not on a plugin's direct dependency.

(By the way, this indeed lead to "Java JAXB API is loaded from the [jrt:/java.xml.bind]", which was my goal.)

Comment: Maybe `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api` is included somehow else? As a dependency of your project or of another dependency?

Comment: I updated the question to address your comment.

Comment: Maybe better answer the question yourself: excluding a plugin's direct dependency does not seem possible with current Maven versions.

Comment: Up until now there hasn't been any reason to do this, but this seems like a valid one. Most clean solution I can think of is allowing to override the scope with "none" for plugin dependencies.

Comment: @RobertScholte Would you consider turning your comment into an answer, preferably with a link to where the docs explain this (if they do, I didn't see it) or maybe even an issue addressed at remedying the situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Up until now there hasn't been any reason to do this, but this seems like a valid one. Most clean solution I can think of is allowing to override the scope with "none" for plugin dependencies.

I've created [MNG-6222](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6222) for it, not sure if we'll fix this for a Maven3, but it makes sense to do it at least for the next major.

Comment: Another valid reason: the build-helper plugin depends (directly) on bsh-2.04b (groupId: org.beanshell). bsh versions before 2.06b have a remote execution vulnerability ( https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-2510 ), so it is necessary to eliminate the older bsh. However, the newer version has a new groupId (org.apache-extras.beanshell), so it is not enough to declare org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:2.06b as dependency, org.beanshell:bsh must be excluded, which is (still) not possible with the current maven (3.6.2).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation with `maven-linkcheck-plugin` in the end I did a more brute force approach to remove the `doxia-linkcheck` dependency and make it use [my fork](https://github.com/trajano/maven-doxia-tools) by forking `maven-linkcheck-plugin` and creating [my own](https://github.com/trajano/maven-plugins/tree/trajano-linkcheck) with the proper dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Check your dependency list with dependency:tree and solve whichever lib is introducing that lib dependency, then exclude it. Maybe your dependency couldn't be a direct one.

Just follow your dependency hierarchy

Comment: The dependency is not introduced by a lib but by the plugin and I know where it comes from - my question is why the exclusion mechanism doesn't work.