# Eclipse Okhttp Error - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion

Tags: java, eclipse, okhttp

I try to use Okhttp and Scarlet library but when I run project this exception throws.
how can I fix it? I search about it and I found out that the version of https is not the same in different library I added to my maven.in my maven dependency i see okhttp-4.9.1.jar and I do NOT know how i can change the version of that.
please help me ...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.kt:1073)
    at crypto.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

my pom.xml file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.cripto</groupId>
  <artifactId>crypto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinder.scarlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.12</version>
   </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinder.scarlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>scarlet</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.12</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinder.scarlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>message-adapter-gson</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.12</version>
   </dependency>
   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```
    public static String Url = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443" ;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient() ; 
        System.out.println(client) ;
        
        
        Scarlet scarlet = new Scarlet.Builder()
                .webSocketFactory(OkHttpClientUtils.newWebSocketFactory(client,Url))
                .addMessageAdapterFactory(new GsonMessageAdapter.Factory())
                //.addStreamAdapterFactory(new RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
                .build() ;
        
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like incompatible jar's

Comment: Add stacktrace as text not as image

Comment: how can I fix that ? @Jens

Answer (score 2):

To view where the okhttp dependency is coming from please run the below command this will display the dependency in a tree format

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Once you figure out where the dependency is populated from, you can exclude([How to exclude dependency in a Maven plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028534/how-to-exclude-dependency-in-a-maven-plugin)) okhttp from there, and add your required version.

Answer (score 0):

okio version used is 1.13 .The version required for the okhttp 4.9.1 is higher.  Okhttp will bring the dependency as transitive dependency of okio .